# Multiple words movement keyboard shortcut

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I have not seen this answered anywhere, so here it goes.

I am working for the moment at work with Visual Studio and a generic shortcut that seems to facilitate movement word-by-word is `Ctrl+left arrow` (or `Ctrl+right arrow`). Moreover, with `Ctrl+Home` or `Ctrl+End`, one moves to the beginning or the end of the line, accordingly. Is there some Vim-like shortcut that I can use or program into the editor so that I can move e.g. 3 words to the right? Keep pressing the arrow key gets tedious. I know of the VsVim plugin, but I would examine (if there are any) more options, maybe even applicable outside the context of Visual Studio. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use my [Visual Commander](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/) extension to chain Visual Studio commands like this:

```
public void Run(EnvDTE80.DTE2 DTE, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package package) 
{
    DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.WordNext");
    DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.WordNext");
    DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.WordNext");
}
```

And then you can assign a shortcut to this new command.

Comment: Interesting! I will take a look on it, thanks :)